# Есть ли какие-то общепринятые шаблоны для написания ботов?

Tags: c#, telegram-bot

Пишу бота для телеграмма. Как не гуглил, а везде лишь мануалы по отправке сообщений и прочего. 
Меня интересует архитектура бота.

Мой бот простой и по сути заменяет UI программы. Я сделал что-то вроде state-machine, но без явных переходов от одного состояния к другому. Т.е. у меня есть куча классов-наследников BaseBotState класса с методом Activate.

Текущее состояние хранится в объекте, описывающем пользователя.

Функция Activate изменяет текущее состояние пользователя и при следующем сообщении вызывается уже другой State.

Есть ли более правильные подходы похожие на мой? Этакий best-practices?

Извиняюсь, если вопрос не совсем конкретный.

Comment: В построение приложения нету каких либо шаблонов, по которым строго надо писать проект, есть паттерны, некий набор рекомендаций, который направлен на грамотное решение определенных задач. Вы например описали [паттерн "Состояние"](https://metanit.com/sharp/patterns/3.6.php) и если вы его "грамотно" реализовали, то что же вы хотите улучшить то? Давайте пример того, что у вас и то, что в итоге хотите, может что и подскажем, а так, уж извините, каждый пишет приложение по своему, например часто в ботах встречаются IoC контейнеры с сервисами, ибо это удобно и легко масштабируется.

Comment: Соглашусь с предыдущим оратором. Несмотря на то, что вы найдете много интересного просто погуглив `chatbot best practice architecture`, при написании своего бота все равно придется учитывать и проектировать его с учетом вашей специфики.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ, спасибо за ответ!
Знать бы, что я хочу) Просто смотрю на то, что получается и кажется, что можно было бы сделать проще и красивее. 
Вас понял. Пошел в гугл)

Comment: @АлександрЛи Если вы считаете, что можно проще и красивее, то это скорей всего возможно. Как я уже говорил - дайте нам то, с чем мы можем работать (пример кода, который у вас сейчас), тогда может и посоветуем что. Сейчас на ваш вопрос можно ответить наверно так: "Да, может и есть", но вам же это не даст нечего, верно?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В свое время тоже задавался этим вопросом. Бота правда так и не написал. Но мысль была примерно следующая.

Есть такие вещи как WorkflowEngine. Их много, от очень старых, предложенных Microsoft до OpenSource реализаций. В нем мы можем задавать состояния в которых находится "таска" и куда она может перейти в зависимости от условий.

По сути наш диалог с ботом это и есть переходы по состояниям (по дереву состояний). Это и есть конечный автомат с набором состояний и переходов. Но чтобы самому не изобретать велосипед, я бы взял за основу какой-нибудь WorkflowEngine. А для работы с данными и внешними сервисами можно использовать обычную монолитную архитектуру с типовыми Provider'ами и Service'ами работающими через IoC контейнер.

Боты обычно не сильно сложные а потому нет смысла городить какие-то микросервисы.

Comment: Спасибо за наводку.